# Can I pre-fill the field of a new object in Silverstripe 4 via the URL?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

The Silverstripe project I'm working on at the moment has an Object with a field called `Code`:

```
class ObjectName extends DataObject
{
  private static $db = [
    'Title' => 'Varchar',
    'Code' => 'Varchar',
    'Description' => 'HTMLText',
  ];
```

The following URL will open the create a new Object screen (in local dev) in the CMS: `http://localhost.app/admin/object-management/ObjectName/EditForm/field/ObjectName/item/new`

We'd like to be able to append something to that URL to pre-fill the `Code` field of a new object.

e.g. `http://localhost.app/admin/object-management/ObjectName/EditForm/field/ObjectName/item/new?Code=CodeGoesHere`

Is this possible within the current framework? Or would it require custom modification to the CMS? If it requires custom modification what approach should I use?

Comment: In the backend it sounds scary without a proper validation of the newly created item. You might hook into `DataObject::populateDefaults()` and check `Controller::curr()->request->getVars()` to prefill the new item.

Comment: Are you using `GridFieldDetailForm` to scaffold a form used to edit that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preset the value of the FormField by adding the following code to your ObjectName class:

```
public function populateDefaults() {
    parent::populateDefaults();
    $code = Controller::curr()->getRequest()->getVar("Code");
    $this->Code = $code;
}
```

This fetches the Code param from the URL and presets the value of the new ObjectName with this value before the fields are scaffolded. The default scaffolder uses the values of the calling DataObject to fill in the FormFields, so your GET-param will be shown to the user.